# css position absolute with top and bottom both

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am using `position: absolute;` on a div.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akash4pj/tDQWN/5028/)

My code is:

```
.ab {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

I want to know why is it on top even if I specified `bottom: 0`?
Is there any priority issue between top and bottom ? Or what is the reason?

Comment: remove your top:0 and it will be on bottom!

Answer (score 17):

From Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

> When both `top` and `bottom` are specified, as long as `height` is unspecified, `auto`, or `100%`, both `top` and `bottom` distances will be respected. Otherwise, **if `height` is constrained in any way, the `top` property takes precedence and the `bottom` property is ignored**.

In your example, you've declared a set `height` as well as both a `top` and `bottom` position, so the `top` position takes precedence, and the `bottom` is ignored (and regardless of the order you list `top` and `bottom`).

Answer (score 7):

Top and left take priority over bottom and right.

But note that you're only seeing this behavior because you specified a height.  If you had specified `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` without a fixed height, then the div would stretch from top to bottom of its first ancestor with non-static positioning.  Specify all four without height or width, and it will fill the whole available area of that parent, [as you can see in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/4U9Yu/).

Comment: Shouldn't the jsFiddle demo work for `position: relative` as well? It doesn't and I can't seem to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All browsers start counting coordinate from top of the page.
You have a top property and height property. First set the top position of the element then his height and then bottom position.

If you remove height property - your block be from top to bottom. (100% height);

Answer (score 1):

CSS prioritises top/left over bottom/right.  If you provide both, it will use top/left instead of bottom/right.

There's no legitimate case for providing both (if you have a defined height and width) though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `top:` has higher priority than `bottom`:
if you are using both `top` and `bottom`. It will allign to the value given by `top`.

`Top` and `Left` has more priority